# How to short or group data according to data value in xslt

Tags: java, xslt

I am working in xslt in which I try to generate a table for particular status and fill data in it, for that need following logic

```
<xsl:variable name="dataRowset1" select="ROWSET1"/>
<xsl:for-each select="$dataRowset1/ROWSET1_ROW">
<xsl:if test="contains($dataRowset1/ROWSET1_ROW/STATUS, 'DONE')">
    <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="big">DONE</fo:block>
```

First time status is DONE then create table and fill data

```
<fo:table width="100%">
                    <xsl:call-template name="table-column-define"/>
            <fo:table-body>
                    <xsl:call-template name="table-header"/>
                <xsl:for-each select="$dataRowset1/ROWSET1_ROW">
                    <xsl:if test="contains(STATUS, 'DONE')">                                    
                        <xsl:call-template name="table-data"/>                                                              
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </fo:table-body>
        </fo:table>
```

For next time status is DONE then do nothing, because table for that status already created

```
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Can you show a small sample of your XML in this case? Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand your question. Could you post an example of the XML input and the expected output?